# How to avoid race condition when using a lock-file to avoid two instances of a script running simultaneously?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, locking, mutex

A typical approach to avoid two instances of the same script running simultaneously looks like this:

```
[ -f ".lock" ] && exit 1
touch .lock
# do something
rm .lock
```

Is there a better way to lock on files from a shell-script, avoiding a race condition? Must directories be used instead?

Comment: Questions should be marked "[solved]" by selecting an answer, not by editing the title and adding "[solved]".

Comment: problem is, I can't mark my own answer as "accepted"

Comment: I don't think your answer is the best one, frankly :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there is indeed a race condition in the sample script. You can use bash's `noclobber` option in order to get a failure in case of a race, when a different script sneaks in between the `-f` test and the `touch`.

The following is a sample code-snippet (inspired by [this article](https://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html)) that illustrates the mechanism:

```
if (set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; 
then
   # This will cause the lock-file to be deleted in case of a
   # premature exit.
   trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT

   # Critical Section: Here you'd place the code/commands you want
   # to be protected (i.e., not run in multiple processes at once).

   rm -f "$lockfile"
   trap - INT TERM EXIT
else
   echo "Failed to acquire lock-file: $lockfile." 
   echo "Held by process $(cat $lockfile)."
fi
```

Comment: In case anyone else was wondering what the `$$` does, it gives back the PID (process ID) of the running script.

Answer (score 10):

Try flock command:

```
exec 200>"$LOCK_FILE"
flock -e -n 200 || exit 1
```

It will exit if the lock file is locked. It is atomic and it will work over recent version of NFS.

I did a test. I have created a counter file with 0 in it and executed the following in a loop on two servers simultaneously 500 times:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 200>/nfs/mount/testlock
flock -e 200

NO=`cat /nfs/mount/counter`
echo "$NO"
let NO=NO+1
echo "$NO" > /nfs/mount/counter
```

One node was fighting with the other for the lock. When both runs finished the file content was 1000. I have tried multiple times and it always works!

Note: NFS client is RHEL 5.2 and server used is NetApp.

Comment: Reasonably good coverage on flock: in my sampling, I have it on Cygwin and Linux, but not Solaris or Mac.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the syntax a bit more? I am especially wondering about `exec 200>"$LOCK_FILE"`. Gonna figure this out with the man pages, but your answer would be much better if it explained what these lines do.

Comment: Bash 3.2 manual, section 3.6: "Redirections using file descriptors greater than 9 should be used with care, as they may conflict with file descriptors the shell uses internally." Intense use of FD 200 (such as 500 times in a row from multiple processes) could cause problems, no?

Answer (score 4):

Lock your script (against parallel run)

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex

FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a directory is atomic, and fails if it already exists if you don't use `-p`, so

```
 mkdir $lockName || exit 1
```

works.

...but use `flock` instead.

Answer (score -1):

seems like I've found an easier solution: man lockfile

Comment: Note that lockfile is not portable - it might not available; it's part of procmail (AFAIK).

Comment: The shell is more portable than procmail, in so far as you're more likely to have bash than procmail. I have bash on Solaris, Linux, Mac and Windows here. `lockfile` isn't on any of them.

Comment: I wrote a bash script using noclobber that mimics some of the behavior of Procmail's lockfile. It should be portable, and you can find it here: http://www.codng.com/2011/05/file-locks-in-bash.html