# Concurrent or lock access in bash script function

Tags: bash, function, shell, concurrency

does anyone know how to lock on a function in bash script?
I wanted to do something like in java (like synchronize), ensuring that each file saved in monitored folder is on hold ever tries to use submit function.

an excerpt from my script:

```
(...)
```

ON_EVENT () {
   local date = $1
   local time = $2
   local file = $3
   sleep 5
   echo "$date $time New file created: $file"
   submit $file
}

**submit () {
   local file = $1 
   python avsubmit.py -f $file -v
   python dbmgr.py -a $file 
}**

if [ ! -e "$FIFO" ]; then 
  mkfifo "$FIFO"
fi

inotifywait -m -e "$EVENTS" --timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --format '%T %f' "$DIR" > "$FIFO" &
INOTIFY_PID=$!

trap "on_exit" 2 3 15

while read date time file
do
  on_event $date $time $file &
done < "$FIFO"

on_exit

I'm using inotify to monitor a folder when a new file is saved. For each file saved (received),  submit to VirusTotal service (avsubmit.py) and TreathExpert (dbmgr.py).
Concurrent access would be ideal to avoid blocking every new file created in monitored folder, but lock submit function should be sufficient.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
if (set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then
   trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT
   # Your code here
   rm -f "$lockfile"
   trap - INT TERM EXIT
else
   echo "Failed to acquire $lockfile. Held by $(cat $lockfile)"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Any code using `rm` in combination with `trap` or similar facility is inherently flawed against ungraceful kills, panics, system crashes, newbie sysadmins, etc. The flaw is that the lock needs to be manually cleaned after such catastrophic event for the script to run again. That may or may not be a problem for you. It is a problem for those managing many machines or wishing to have an unplugged vacation once in a while.

A modern solution using a file descriptor lock has been around for a while - [I detailed it here](http://blog.didenko.com/2010/08/locking-for-daemons-in-bash.html) and [a working example is on the GitHub here](https://gist.github.com/didenko/a92beec14ce2ca1c98f3). If you do not need to track process ID for whatever monitoring or other reasons, [there is an interesting suggestion for a self-lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057234/bash-flock-exit-if-cant-acquire-lock/7305448#7305448) (I did not try it, not sure of its portability guarantee).

Comment: Thanks. I just used a version of your flock solution. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [lock file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) to determine whether or not the file should be submitted.

Inside your `ON_EVENT` function, you should check if the appropriate lock file exists before calling the `submit` function.  If it does exist, then return, or sleep and check again later to see if it's gone.  If it doesn't exist, then create the lock and call `submit`.  After the `submit` function completes, then delete the lock file.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325628/race-condition-in-the-common-lock-on-file) for implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

But I liked that files can not get lock stay on the waiting list (cache) to be submitted then or later.

I currently have something like this:

```
lockfile="./lock"
```

on_event() {
  local date=$1
  local time=$2
  local file=$3
  sleep 5
  echo "$date $time New file created: $file"
  if (set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then 
     trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT
     **submit_samples $file** 
     rm -f "$lockfile"
     trap - INT TERM EXIT
  else
     echo "Failed to acquire lockfile: $lockfile." 
     echo "Held by $(cat $lockfile)"
  fi
}

**submit_samples() {**
  **local file=$1
  python avsubmit.py -f $file -v 
  python dbmgr.py -a $file** 
**}**

Thank you once again ...

Answer (score 0):

I had proplems wiith this approach and found a better solution:

Procmail comes with a **lockfile** command which does what I wanted:

```
lockfile -5 -r10 /tmp/lock.file
do something very important
rm -f /tmp/lock.file
```

lockfile will try to create the specified lockfile. If it exists it iwll retry in 5 seconds, this will be repeated for maximum 10 times. If can create the flile it goes on with the script.

Another solution are the lockfile-progs in debian, example directly from the man page:

```
Locking a file during a lengthy process:

     lockfile-create /some/file
     lockfile-touch /some/file &
     # Save the PID of the lockfile-touch process
     BADGER="$!"
     do-something-important-with /some/file
     kill "${BADGER}"
     lockfile-remove /some/file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
inotifywait -q -m -r -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f $DIR | 
parallel -u python avsubmit.py -f {}\; python dbmgr.py -a {}
```

It will run at most one python per CPU when a file is written (and closed). That way you can bypass all the locking, and you get the added benefit that you avoid a potential race condition where a file is immediately overwritten (how do you make sure that both the first and the second version was checked?).

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
```

Watch the intro videos for GNU Parallel to learn more:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1