# bash flock: exit if can't acquire lock

Tags: bash, concurrency, flock

The following lock mechanism is used for preventing a `cron` job from running concurrently:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Before critical section"
(
    flock -e 200
    echo "In critical section"
    sleep 5
) 200>/tmp/blah.lockfile
echo "After critical section"
```

When running two instances together, the later waits until the first finishes, and then runs. This can cause backlogs of scripts waiting to run.

How do I alter this script so that if `flock` can't acquire the lock, it terminates the script? I've tried `-n` without success.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
flock -n -e 200 || exit 1
```

`flock -n` tells you it failed by returning a failure code (something other than zero).  You could instead do `set -e` at the top of your script to make it exit when it sees any unchecked error.

Depending on your application, you might want to `exit 0` to indicate success when the lock can't be acquired.

Answer (score 14):

We use exclusive lock on the script file itself, `$0` is the name of command file.

```
exec 200<$0
flock -n 200 || exit 1
```

The whole solution is in two lines of code. But the trick is to open $0 for reading and then obtain exclusive lock for it.

Comment: It would be nice to document the cases when this can fail. I suspect it will fail if `$0` contains spaces, and it will fail if `$0` does not contain the path to the running script (e.g. the script is elsewhere but on the `PATH`).

Comment: $0 should still have the path if it's in $PATH. One case where it doesn't work is under dash.

Comment: exec 200<"$0" # <- double quotes prevent the problem with space characters mentioned above

Comment: In case you're wondering what's so special about the number 200: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13551882/1456173